# multilevel modeling (lmer)

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I'm trying to run some main effects models with the lmer function (lme4 package) in R but they keep coming out as a singular fit.  It's possible this is because the model is overfit, but even when I remove variables from the model it still reports a singular fit.

My intuition is that this is because the independent variables are "situation-level" or repeated measure variables with 2000+ data points, while the dependent variables are "person-level" variables with around 200 data points. Is there any way (besides collecting more data) to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct, maddiek314. In linear mixed models such as those fit by `lme4`, the outcome must be at the lowest level of the data hierarchy (typically occasion in longitudinal models or individual units in cross-sectional models). Variables that are measured at the person-level can be used as predictors in the model but *not* as outcomes. To look at those as outcomes, you have a couple of options:

1. Aggregate the situation-level predictor variables to the person-level and run a OLS regression. Of course you lose some information in doing this, but when your interest is in the person, it is a valid approach.
2. Use multilevel structural equation modeling in something like [`lavaan`](http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/multilevel.html) or in [`Mplus`](https://www.statmodel.com/), the latter of which is extremely powerful but also costs money to purchase.